# Solutions to $\Gamma(z,1)^2 + \Gamma(z,1) = 0 $?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, special-functions, functional-equations, gamma-function

Let $\Gamma(z,1) $ be the well-known incomplete gamma function : $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt $

Now I am curious to find solutions to

$$\Gamma(z,1)^2 + \Gamma(z,1) = 0 $$

We can ofcourse reduce this too all complex solutions of either

$$\Gamma(z,1) = 0 $$

or

$$\Gamma(z,1) = -1 $$

I heard that this function is an entire function so the equation $\Gamma(z,1)^2 + \Gamma(z,1) = 0 $ must have solutions.

I think that $\Gamma(z,1) = 0 $ has no (finite) solutions.

I assume most solutions to $\Gamma(z,1) = -1 $ must have $-3 < Re(z) < 3 $ due to the functional equation this function satisfies. ( $\Gamma(z+1,1) = z \Gamma(z,1) + e^{-1} $ )

I know a bit about complex analysis and contour integrals.
But I have no efficient method to find the zero's.
I would like to have the values and some insight into them.
How far are the zero's apart from eachother ?

Im aware of another identity for strictly real $z < 1$ :

$$ \Gamma(z,1)=\frac{e^{z-1}}{\Gamma(1-z)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} t^{-z}}{1+t} dt$$

Not sure if that could help.

I was only able to find $t=4.86853..+5.66062..i$ and its complex conjugate as solutions to $\Gamma(t,1) = -1$

edit :

Perhaps the following limits might be helpful :

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} Re(x^2 \Gamma(1+e+x i,1)  ) = -1$$

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} Im(x \Gamma(1+e+ x i,1) ) = e^{-1} i $$

Comment: There are infinitely many zeros, eg. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+Gamma%5B2.7%2Bix%2C1%5D%3D-1

Comment: I was only able to find $ z= 4.86853 + 5.66062i $ and its complex conjugate.

Comment: I must note that CAPITAL gamma is actually the usual way to denote this function.

Comment: edited with capital gamma :)

Comment: Have you considered Lagrange inversion?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I considered Lagrange inversion , argument principle ( contour integral ) and standard numerical methods ( like newton ).
Maybe I missed something ofcourse ...